# cannot set image while inflating layout on android

Tags: android, xml, image, layout, bitmap

I am trying to add a small image in a row of my ExpandableList. Below you can see the code of the getchildview method of my custom adapter. It works perfectly for setting dynamic text but it fails when i want to add an image.

I don't understand why the commands for adding an image are completely ignored by the application. I have tried 2 versions, just to see both fail.

I do not get any runtime error, just the images aren't loaded. 
Moreover, i know that at least "setImageBitmap" works because i use it elsewhere with success.

The images referenced are 9x10 png files.

Please help me because i don't think i am missing anything but the images aren't shown at all.

I have tried to set a background color (setBackgroundColor) on relativelayout l but it didn't have effect too. So i think it is something graphic related, but i can't find any error in my approach.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.titoli2_gruppo_riga, null)
        String s;
        s=prodotti.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)[DSP];
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.disponibile);
        if(s.equals("true"))                    
            ((ImageView) l.findViewById(R.id.tgr_dispon)).setImageBitmap(bm);
        else
            ((ImageView) l.findViewById(R.id.tgr_dispon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.nondispon);           
        ((TextView) l.findViewById(R.id.tgr_descr)).setText(prodotti.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)[DES]);
        ((TextView) l.findViewById(R.id.tgr_prezz)).setText("€"+prodotti.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)[PRE]);
        ((TextView) l.findViewById(R.id.tgr_note)).setText(prodotti.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)[NOT]);                
        ((TextView) l.findViewById(R.id.tgr_sigla)).setText(prodotti.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)[SIG]);


        return l;
}
```

You can see the XML i am inflating, here http://pastebin.com/DwxdxJSK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you checked you **Graphical Layout** in you XML file, **Image is not visible in you Graphical Layout** because of `TextView with id as tgr_descr is given match_parent` so you Imageview is not Visible.

For Checking whether image is visible just use  `android:src="@drawable/icon"`

Try this Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">
<ImageView      android:id="@+id/tgr_dispon"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tgr_descr"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
<TextView       android:id="@+id/tgr_descr" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tgr_prezz" android:text="descr"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:padding="7dp"/>

<TextView       android:id="@+id/tgr_prezz" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  android:text="prezzo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:padding="7dp"/>

<TextView       android:id="@+id/tgr_note" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/tgr_descr"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="note"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:paddingLeft="7dp"/>
<TextView       android:id="@+id/tgr_sigla" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tgr_note"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tgr_descr" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="sigla" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:paddingLeft="7dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'll test your suggestion. i'll be back soon

Comment: anyway your direction has been useful, i am now retesting my XML block by block to find the hidder component :)

Comment: @STTLCU I checked..It's working.. Assign String s="true" and try for static value

Comment: of course i removed the string check part altogether to try the code :)

Comment: @STTLCU In you graphical layout is it possible for view you image?

Comment: i have other layouts with images already implemented (and showing) in this same app

Comment: Ok Venky i must have made some copy-paste error, because i now retried and the layout you suggested is working. Anyway, the problem was tgr_descr which was overlapping and thus hiding the image. Thank you very much. Answer accepted